# How to sync multiple AVPlayer while play the same local video

Tags: ios, objective-c, video, avplayer

I have to play the same local video file with the AVPlayer at the same time, and I created 4 AVPlayer instance, and the AVPlayerLayers was added to tha same layer. But the question is that 4 player were not begin at the same time. How to make them begin at the same time? here is my code:

```
self.players = @[].mutableCopy;
    CMAudioClockCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, &_syncClock);
    AVPlayerItem *item = [[AVPlayerItem alloc] initWithURL:self.url];
    for (NSInteger i = 0; i<playerNum; i++) {
        AVPlayer *avPlayer = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:item.copy];
        AVPlayerLayer *playerLayer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:avPlayer];
        //设置模式
        playerLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill;
        playerLayer.contentsScale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
        CGPoint pos = [playerOriginArr[i] CGPointValue];
        playerLayer.frame = CGRectMake(pos.x, pos.y, playerSize.width, playerSize.height);
        [self.playBackBgView.layer addSublayer:playerLayer];
        avPlayer.masterClock = _syncClock;
        [avPlayer.currentItem addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"status" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];
        [avPlayer play];
        [self.players addObject:avPlayer];
    }

- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object
                    change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {
if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"status"] && [object isKindOfClass:[AVPlayerItem class]]) {
    AVPlayerItem *playerItem = (AVPlayerItem *)object;
    if (playerItem.status == AVPlayerStatusReadyToPlay) {
        for (AVPlayer *player in self.players) {
            if (player.currentItem == playerItem) {
                [player prerollAtRate:1.0 completionHandler:^(BOOL finished) {
                    if (finished) {
                    }
                }];
                player.automaticallyWaitsToMinimizeStalling = NO;//如果是
                NSLog(@"setRate");
                [player setRate:1.0 time:kCMTimeInvalid atHostTime:CMClockGetTime(_syncClock)];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Can't you create just one `AVPlayer` and create multiple `AVPlayerLayers`s from that? Surely the layers would be synchronized.

Comment: @RhythmicFistman create just one AVPlayer and create multiple AVPlayerLayers solved my problem. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Great! I've turned this speculative comment into an authoritative answer.

Comment: I'm sorry I gave that answer, as now I'm back trying to understand how to use `CMAudioClockCreate` to sync video to custom audio and this is the only hit on StackOverflow!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create just one `AVPlayer` and create multiple `AVPlayerLayer`s from that.

The layers will be synchronized.

Comment: Can I use the the same `AVPlayer` in `AVPlayerLayer` and `AVPlayerViewController`?

Comment: You can, and the playback in both is synchronised.

Comment: I'm facing an issue with this. The video stops while the audio is still playing when I use the same `AVPlayer` with `AVPlayerViewController`. What's the solution for this?

Comment: I don't know - can you you ask a new question showing what you're doing?

Comment: Here is the question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53352205/sync-video-in-avplayerlayer-and-avplayerviewcontroller?noredirect=1#comment93582150_53352205